# How to call information from radiobutton in separate activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, radio-button

In my app, I have music playing when the app starts. If the user goes to settings they can change the volume or turn the music on and off, however I do not know how to recall the information from the radio buttons to turn the music on or off in other activities. I know if I turn the music off in the main activity under onCreate it will listen to the radio buttons, but I want music playing when the app starts and when you resume the activity it inputs the info from the radio buttons.

This is the code of my main activity

```
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Intent svc = new Intent(this, music.class
            );
            startService(svc);

        }

        public void onPlayPressed(View view) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Game.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }

        public void onSettingsPressed(View view) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Settings.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }

        public void onHowtoPressed(View view) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), HowtoPlay.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {

            super.onResume();

            
        }



        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {


            super.onDestroy();
            Intent svc = new Intent(this, music.class);
            stopService(svc);


        }
    }
```

and this is the code of my Settings activity

````
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {


    private RadioGroup radioGroup;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
            final Intent svc = new Intent(this, music.class
            );


            RadioButton rdb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.on);
            rdb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();
                    // Check which radiobutton was pressed
                    if (checked){
                        startService(svc);

                    }
                    else{
                        stopService(svc);
                    }
                }
            });
            RadioButton rdb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.off);
            rdb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();
                    // Check which radiobutton was pressed
                    if (checked){
                        stopService(svc);

                    }
                    else{
                        startService(svc);
                    }
                }
            });
            final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        int curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        SeekBar volControl = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        volControl.setMax(maxVolume);
        volControl.setProgress(curVolume);
        volControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, arg1, 0);
            }
        });



    }

        public void onMainMenuPressed(View view){

        Intent myIntent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }

        public void onResumePressed (View view){

        Intent myIntent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),Game.class);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
    }
    } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences with simple boolean flag.

You should use onCheckedChangeListener on the radio group rather than onClickListener on individual radio button, like so:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(...) {
        getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0).edit().putBoolean("music", rdb.isChecked()).apply();
    }
});
```

Then inside other activity:

```
boolean music = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0).getBoolean("music", true);
```

Then check value of the flag to determine whether or not to start the music service.

Comment: Thank you for answering! But I am having trouble getting this to work. First, Android Studio wants me to implement methods when I paste the OnCheckedChangeListener, and what is supposed to go where the ellipses are?

Comment: The only method you need to implement is onCheckedChanged(). You need two parameters where the ellipses are, one of type `RadioGroup` and one of type `int` as described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener#public-methods_1). I neglected to include that information because Android Studio can autocomplete the method implementation for you if you start typing `new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()` within the parentheses of the `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` method.

Comment: I see, thank you! How do I check the value of the flag then?

Comment: Just like you've done in your onClick() method: `if (music) { startService(svc); }`. You'll obviously need to have the `svc` variable defined in the other activity too.